# Alternatives for enabling SSL on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, https

I have an existing AWS EC2 instance which contains both an application server and a web server (apache). My external DNS directs traffic from www.x.com, api.x.com, oa.x.com to the instance via it's elastic IP. www.x.com is served from the web server and the other sub-domains are served from the app server. All traffic is HTTPS and letsencrypt is installed on EC2 for the SSL certs. This works fine.

Now I am rolling a new EC2 instance since the existing one is too small, and starting to behave strange. All is fine except I can't install letsencrypt on the new instance. After reading up on it I found out this is not really supported, which is why I decided to use AWS certs instead (ACM).

However, two days later I have still not been able to get SSL to work. I have tried to create a Cloudfront distribution. The SSL works just fine between Client and Cloudfront but I cannot get the traffic between Cloudfront and EC2 to use SSL.

Q1: Is it possible to get SSL/HTTPS between Cloudfront and EC2 without any other nodes/components (like load balancers)?

Q2: Is it better/easier to get SSL/HTTPS in my setup if I add a loadbalancer in front of the EC2 instance (even if I just have on instance)?

Q3: Any other options?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction, this drives me nuts, especially as it´s Friday night :-)
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**Let's Encrypt**

Let's Encrypt works with any host on the public internet, including AWS. I use Let's Encrypt on my AWS EC2 instance, and you've used LE on EC2 before. I'm confused why you think LE doesn't work with AWS.

I have a tutorial on EC2 / LE [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/). The version number of the software I use "ACME" is potentially an old version now, if you use that you should check for a new version.

**Instance Size**

If you need a larger instance, you can just stop your instance, change the size, and start it again. If you need a larger EBS volume you can expand the volume.

**AWS Certificate Manager**

This statement on the [ECM FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/) is slightly confusing suggests you can't use public ACM certificates on EC2 instances.

Q: Can I use certificates on Amazon EC2 instances or on my own servers?

You can use private certificates issued with ACM Private CA with EC2 instances, containers, and on your own servers. At this time, public ACM certificates can be used only with specific AWS services. See With which AWS services can I use ACM certificates?

**Conclusion**

I suggest that you go back to using Let's Encrypt. If you need help please start another question saying what you're trying to achieve, what's not working, and show any relevant logs.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I hadn't seen your tutorial and I will give it a try for sure. The reason why I thought LE and EC2 doesn't work, is because I couldn't get it to run. 
('sudo ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --debug --standalone -d www.x.com -d api.x.com -d oauth.x.com' => Sorry, I don't know how to bootstrap Certbot on your operating system!...) and googling on this error indicates the limitations of LE and EC2. E.g. [first reply on this](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/help-with-certbot-on-the-new-amazon-linux-2/49399). I will post another question if needed.

Comment: The Let's Encrypt client might not work well on Amazon Linux, it didn't when I tried, but don't generalize that to EC2. Amazon Linux isn't a great OS mostly due to the lack of support and community knowledge. Use Ubuntu or something. Let's Encrypt client should work fine on that. Try the client I recommended, worked well for me.

Comment: True, it's not EC2 of course, just the Amazon Linux. I will try Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to seem like overkill but it works rather well. Set up a public facing application load balancer in front of the EC2 instance, and do HTTP->HTTPS SSL Termination with the Load Balancer. This will make it easy for you to swap out certs if you need to at the AWS level rather than the instance level. Update the DNS to point to the Load Balancer rather than the EC2 instance. There is a cost associated with this though, but it would probably solve the issue for sure.

Comment: Thanks Justin, this was what I thought and I'm glad you confirmed it. Using Cloudfront is likely not the correct way to get about this so I'll try a load balancer if I continue having problems with Letsencrypt.

Comment: If I understand correctly I cannot terminate the SSL in the Load Balancer, because then the client/browser would still see a Not Secure warning in the browser? The Load Balancer will verify my AWS certificate (that is in ACM) but will then have to continue talk over HTTPS to the EC2 instance, is that correct? 
If so, I still need a certificate on EC2 and since I cannot use the one from ACM there what do I use on EC2, and have I really gained anything by introducing a Load Balancer? 
Maybe I should generate another certificate in ACM, a private one, and use this between EC2 <-> LB?

Comment: Ok, I understood it might be better posting the above as a [new question](https://serverfault.com/questions/935625/do-i-need-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-ec2-server-even-when-i-have-a-load-balancer) instead.